# Updating a table in Django

Tags: mysql, django

I have a table named Email in `models.py`. I want to add additional columns to it. I have tried adding the additional column to the `models.py` file, saving it, and then doing a

`$ python manage.py syncdb`,

but it is not updating the table columns (I imagine because it recognizes that the table already exists in the database and skips over it).

How do I update a table that already exists in django?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[django]+migrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`syncdb` creates tables if the table does not already exist. Any alterations in table that already exists is not handled by `syncdb`. Either you have to manually alter the tables or use a migration tool like [south](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Django does not support automatic changes to the schema.  See the [Django book chapter on models](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter05/), in particular the section titled "Making Changes to a Database Schema".  Some third-party support for database migration is available.